# Is it possible to measure the liquid amount in Quantum Tanks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I started using [Quantum Tanks](http://ftbwiki.org/Quantum_Tank) to store my liquids (FTB Ultimate pack).  I use liquiducts to pipe the liquids from the Quantum Tanks to their target locations.

Is there a way to measure/display/meter the liquid level in Quantum Tanks?  I know I can walk up to it and right-click it to see the interface, but I am more interested in sending a signal when the amount of liquid gets below/above a set point.  I'm guessing it is not possible, but I thought I would ask in case someone had a solution.

Comment: As with everything quantum, Quantum Tanks obey the [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) - once you figure out how much is inside, you won't know _what_ is inside any more :-P

Comment: Are you playing on a server or singleplayer? (If singleplayer, you might consider installing [OpenCCSensors](http://www.computercraft.info/wiki/index.php?title=OpenCCSensors) and using its Tank Sensor Card, which works on Quantum Tanks. The downside is maintaining a customised install.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am playing on a server, so unfortunately I cannot modify anything.  That sensor card sounds pretty cool though!   Zommuter lol!

Comment: This may seem dumb but have you tried comparators?

Comment: @new The comparator is from 1.5 and FTB is back on 1.4.7.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie He might be using the beta 1.5, I dunno.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Yeah- still on 1.4.7 - comparators would be nice though!

Comment: Have you tried the sensors from Nuclear Control?

Comment: @ItsNotALie FTB *Ultimate* is locked to 1.4.7 and won't update. The betas you're thinking of are Unleashed and Unhinged, which aren't Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

In the ultimate pack for feed the beast you can use a [Nuclear Control](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Nuclear_Control) Liquid Sensor Kit and a computer how full a tank show it visibly without any extra addons.

I'll post some example code and pictures when I get home from work but if you wrap a nuclear information reader as a peripheral you have a .get(slot) API which gives you the required information, more information [on the Misc Peripherals thread](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/4587-cc153mc152-miscperipherals-33/).

Comment: Oooh - this sounds neat!  I haven't played with Nuclear Control yet.  I will have to pursue this - and yes, if you have example code and pics, that would be awesome!